# Google Analytics ga:adClicks returning zero

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

For the last year I've been using the google analytics reporting api to retrieve data for a client's app.

Since 19.1.17 the ga:adClicks started returning zeros.
When making a query for the same dates last week the user had clicks, and this week it's all zeros.
Querying earlier dates returns correct data.

```
This is the query - 
data_service.ga().get(
    ids='ga:profile_id',
    start_date='2017-01-20',
    end_date='2017-02-03',
    metrics='ga:adClicks,ga:transactionRevenue',
    dimensions='ga:date, ga:campaign, ga:source',
    start_index=1).execute()
```

I'm using the same profile_id as always, and checking all the pages of the report, nothing in the handling of the data changed in this past week.

Answer (score 1):

There have been some changes to the Google Analytics API that may or may not be causing your issue.

> On or after 1/31/2017 non-AdSense linked views will be restricted from
>   querying for AdSense dimensions and metrics. Querying for these
>   dimensions and metrics with a non-AdSense linked views will result in
>   an error.

se google analytics [change log](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/changelog)

Comment: I have this problem too but the view is linked. Under Property > AdSense Linking, I have one AdSense account with 1 linked view "All Web Site Data". When I use the API, I get no error, but a bunch of zeroes for metrics "ga:adsenseRevenue,ga:adsenseAdsClicks,ga:adsensePageImpressions". My scripts run nightly and the first zeroes began after the Feb. 14, 2017 release. How do we make sure our view is linked with AdSense?

Comment: I have followed all the instructions at https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/6084409?hl=en Also I am using V3 of the API with Python 2.7 and google-api-python-client==1.3.1

Comment: Depends on the dimensions used. I can query metrics like clicks, revenue, and impressions as long as I don't ask for the "ga:hour" or "ga:metro" dimension. Once I add "ga:hour" to the request for V3 or V4 endpoints, the data returned is usually all zeroes.

Comment: There isn't data for all of metrics absence dosent deliver hour

Comment: It did up until Feb. 14, 2017. This is a regression in functionality.

Comment: There is already an issue report up for this apparently https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35431494